# Want to prevent MySQL Inner Join two tables giving Unwanted Rows In Result Java Swing

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Dear friends I am developing Java Swing Project and I have 2 Mysql table as follows.

Table Purchase

```
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+
|    Date    | Commodity | PurchPrice | SalePrice | Qty |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+
| 2020-06-10 | A         |        123 |     150.0 |  15 |
| 2020-06-12 | A         |        125 |     150.0 |  25 |
| 2020-06-14 | A         |        120 |     150.0 |  30 |
| 2020-06-16 | A         |        124 |     150.0 |  35 |
| 2020-06-18 | A         |        126 |     160.0 |  40 |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+
```

Table AvailStock

```
+-----------+-----------+-----+
| Commodity | SalePrice | Qty |
+-----------+-----------+-----+
| A         |     150.0 |  25 |
| A         |     160.0 |  30 |
+-----------+-----------+-----+
```

This is my Sql query

```
String query = "SELECT Distinct Date,Purchase.Commodity,AvailStock.Commodity, "
        PurchPrice,Purchase.SalePrice,AvailStock.SalePrice,AvailStock.Qty "
        + "From AvailStock "
        + "Inner Join Purchase "    
        + "On Purchase.SelePrice = AvailStock.SalePrice "
        + "And Purchase.Commodity = AvailStock.Commodity "
        + "Where Commodity =? "
        + "And AvailStock.Qty!=0 ";
```

It gives the following result.

```
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+
|    Date    | Commodity | PurchPrice | SalePrice | Qty |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+
| 2020-06-10 | A         |        123 |       150 |  25 |
| 2020-06-12 | A         |        125 |       150 |  25 |
| 2020-06-14 | A         |        120 |       150 |  25 |
| 2020-06-16 | A         |        124 |       150 |  25 |
| 2020-06-18 | A         |        126 |       160 |  30 |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+
```

It is giving an exaggerated output for Qty

And I want the following result

```
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+
|    Date    | Commodity | PurchPrice | SalePrice | Qty |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+
| 2020-06-16 | A         |        124 |       150 |  25 |
| 2020-06-18 | A         |        126 |       160 |  30 |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+
```

Tried Left join and Right Join istead of Inner Join and all gives the same result!!!.

Here the problem is that Commodity A is having two sale price. viz 150 and 160. Out of these 160 have only one puchase price. So the result in case of Commodity A with sale price 160 is correct.

But in case of Commodity A with Sale price 150 have 4 different purchase price So in result 4 rows are coming corresponding to each purchase price resulting in error with total avalable Quantity.

Somebody please help me to get the desired result.

Note:- Actually this error is happening only to those Commodities which are having different purchase price but same sale price as illustrated in the above table.

Comment: I fail to understand the logic. Can you explain what do you want to get as a result?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space after  `Where Commodity =?`, or does it not matter?

Comment: Dear Impaler I have given the desired result as the last table.

Comment: Dear Strawberry I have editted the query and added the space

Comment: It seems you want to fill the last order only. Is that what you want?

Comment: And what's the PRIMARY KEY on availstock?

Comment: Dear Impaler In Available stock the actual total Quantity is 55 but in result it is 130. Not possible to use Limit.

Comment: Strawberry Sorry No Primary Key. Is it a must?

Comment: Here the problem is that  Commodity A is having two sale price. viz 150 and 160. Out of these 160 have only one puchase price. So the result in case of Commodity A with sale price 160 is correct. But in case of Commodity A with Sale price 150 have 4 different purchase price So in result 4 rows are coming corresponding to each purchase price resulting in error with total avalable Quantity in result

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really have a table.

Comment: Dear Strawberry I have tried the query "Show Keys From table Where Key_name ='PRIMARY' ";  In MySql WorkBench but it returned 0 row. And the table is working and giving results except for the error mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fill the last order only, then you'll need to filter out all "older" rows. You can do this by adding the following extra condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Date,AvailStock.Commodity,
        AvailStock.SalePrice,PurchPrice,AvailStock.Qty
From Purchase
Inner Join AvailStock   
        On Purchase.SalePrice = AvailStock.SalePrice 
        And Purchase.Commodity = AvailStock.Commodity 
Where AvailStock.Commodity ='A'
        And AvailStock.Qty!=0
        and (AvailStock.Commodity, AvailStock.SalePrice, Purchase.Date) in (
  select p.Commodity, p.SalePrice, max(date)
  from Purchase p
  join AvailStock a on a.Commodity = p.Commodity 
                   and a.SalePrice = p.SalePrice
  group by p.Commodity, p.SalePrice
)
```

**EDIT for performance**

The following indexes can theoretically improve the performance of this query:

```
create index ix1 on AvailStock (Commodity, Qty);

create index ix2 on Purchase(Commodity, SalePrice, Date);

create index ix3 on AvailStock (Commodity, SalePrice);
```

Comment: Dear Impaler Max(date) will not solve the problem in general case because the problem here is that Commodity A is having two sale price. viz 150 and 160. Out of these 160 have only one puchase price. So the result in case of Commodity A with sale price 160 is correct. But in case of Commodity A with Sale price 150 have 4 different purchase price So in result 4 rows are coming corresponding to each purchase price resulting in error with total avalable Quantity in result

Comment: Tried with the extra condition you have given. But getting an SQL Exception "No Database Selected". Also tried by changing the last p.purchprice to p.saleprice

Comment: Your columns names and query are inconsistent. Please add your example to a https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: Ok I will do it

Comment: here is the Link to db-fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tkgUqhEJ4FXHHamMqLTNGN/0#&togetherjs=RVRg4MPqGa

Comment: @RenojJoseph Updated the answer. The solution is also in the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tkgUqhEJ4FXHHamMqLTNGN/1

Comment: Dear Impaler thanks for your help. It works. It is taking a few seconds when only one commodity is taken. But it is taking infinite time to open up the table with all the commodities. My database is heavy with about 6000 commodities in purchase and 4000 commodities in available stock. I want the full table for comparison and to find the profit/loss . What to do? Any alternate way?

Comment: @RenojJoseph See edit for performance. In order to improve performance there are many details that need to be analyzed, but I took a guess on a few things and I included the indexes that can be of help. Try adding them, and then you can try running the query again.

Comment: I have tried it and works well now it takes less than 2 minutes to open the full table. Thanks once again Impaler